# UK visa for parents and sister from Ghana to attend graduation refused V4.2 (a) and (c) - should we reapply now?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a visitor visa for my parents and sister to attend my PhD graduation in July and to visit my family for 3 weeks but they have all been refused under V4.2 (a) and (c) - see refusal letters below. Some of the reasons are simply mistakes on my part and that of my parents/sister. I am just wondering whether addressing these issues and reapplying is worth it. For instance I forgot to add my birth certificate to show that they are my parents and my parents did not add their bank statements and land/house documents because apparently they were not asked at the VAC. Is there any hope with reapplying? My graduation is on 17th July and I very much would like for them to be here and to see their grandchildren (which I also stated in the cover letter).

The relevant portions of my parents refusal letter are:[image]
[image]
[image][image]

[image: Sister's refusal letter 1][image: sister's refusal letter 2]

Should we go ahead and reapply now with the right documentations or is it a waste of money and hope? I feel we can easily address their issues but I do not know if that will be enough or they will come up with some other grounds. We plan on adding the land title certificate, rent income book and house valuation as evidence of my parents' ties to Ghana. Will there be grounds to say they do not earn enough money even though there is monthly pension payment for my Dad? I have a very small time window before my graduation is up.

Comment: Finally, read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e/92122#92122 and other answers to similar UK visa questions here by [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow?tab=questions). Everything you would want to know/learn is covered by his answers.

Comment: @paulofosawatomie Thanks Paul. Letters uploaded. I have been going through Gayot Fow's answers which gives me both hope and despair. There are no issues with my sponsorship as I a Lecturer and about to take up a Senior Lectureship position from August. The main concern is my parents' low earnings. Their major asset is the land, house and savings/fixed deposit. Will this be enough? They actually have old school physical savings passbook from their rural bank. I also feel like if I don't reapply for my sister that might raise questions and doubts about this change.

Comment: Is it possible to chat with you somehow? I plan on writing another detailed cover letter to explain the earlier omissions. I could add that my sister is not reapplying because we realise the odds I stack up against her for another refusal. Will that be too crazy? Is it allowed to add pictures of say the house or my parents with their grandkids from the last time we were in Ghana? I feel the more evidence we add the better. The final question is whether it is worth having a legal representation for the application.

Comment: Sadly, the reapplication was also refused so my parents did not get to see my PhD graduation. It does feel hopeless sometimes with the Home Office. The basic reason given is that they doubt that my parents will return after their visit even though I provided all the evidence available to show their economic and social ties to Ghana.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The UK visa application for people from developing countries is akin to a lottery particularly if you are not wealthy. Probably half or more the consular officers believe that anyone from a developing country who is not wealthy would want to migrate to the UK. Someone needs to let them know that the UK (or any developed country for that matter) ain't **all that**